# audio file processing like speed, play mode in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, audiotoolbox, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I have an iphone application and in that, I want to modify music file in my iphone application like changing speed, cutting portion of song, changing play mode etc. After modifying, it should be saved to my iphone application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) is the one you need to look at for playback and real time manipulation.

I started building a library for Audio/Video manipulation and export using AVFoundation. It can handle the trimming of audio for the moment. GitHub link: https://github.com/tulakshana/composer

Comment: I think he is looking for a way to edit and save audio files, not just play them.

Comment: @RakeebHossain, 
Yes, you are correct. https://github.com/tulakshana/composer handles some of the manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the representation of an audio file and then saving it to your device will require you to first initialize the media object, which you can do with [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset).

You will then need to create a mutable composition ([AVMutableComposition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablecomposition)), which creates a copy of your media object for you to edit.

Finally, once you've processed your media, you will need to export it ([AVAssetExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession)).